# What is the relation between conditional random variable and the original one?

Tags: probability

The title might be confusing, so let's directly see the example. Let $\mathbf{X}=(X,Y)$ be a random vector. We know that we can discuss its conditional p.d.f.'s, for example $$f_{X\mid Y=5}(x)=\frac{f(x,5)}{f_Y(5)},$$ where $f$ is the joint p.d.f. and $f_Y$ the marginal p.d.f.

And next, we know that the function $f_{X\mid Y=5}$ is a p.d.f. of some random variable as well, since it can be shown that $\int_{\Bbb R} f_{X\mid Y=5}(x)\,dx=1$ and the other requirements as well.

However, I just wonder what is the expression of the random variable whose p.d.f. is $f_{X\mid Y=5}$? I think every time when such naturally-interested things happened in mathematics, there were always some people mentioning that in the textbook. Is there a terse form of that? I mean, how is such anonymous random variable related to the original random variable $X$ or $Y$? (For example, might it be something like $\frac{X}{f_Y(5)}$?)

Comment: I have seen people write X|Y=5 and use that as any other random variable.

Comment: @PeterKeller I was asking a slightly different thing indeed (I just now edited it for clarity), but I still thank for your information!

Comment: Then i do not understand your question at all. Or in other words the random variable X conditioned on the outcome of Y is the conditional expectation $\mathbb E(X|Y)$.